# git-http-backend binary missing from alpine/3.7/main package

Tags: git, alpine-linux

It appears that the `git-http-backend` binary is missing from the latest alpine linux package (3.7 and upwards). This seems to be the case since git version `2.15+` in the package repo.

I'm hoping I'm just doing something wrong, but is there a reason the package would just drop this binary?

Reproduce:

`$ docker exec -it alpine:latest ash`

`$ apk update`

`$ apk add git`

Now confirm that `cat /usr/libexec/git-core/ | grep http` does *not* yield the `git-http-backend` result.

This is very puzzling.

Does anyone know where I can report this?

Answer (score 10):

`git-http-backend` is available in `git-daemon` package: https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/main/x86/git-daemon

So you need: `apk add git-daemon`